# Why is the reaction enthalpy the same as change in enthalpy for each of the reactants and products?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy, heat

How come the $\Delta H$ of the reaction is the same $\Delta H$ for each of the reactants and products? For example, in an equation, the $\Delta H$ of the reaction is $244 \,\mathrm{kJ}$. When my professor did the problem, I saw that she used that same delta when converting the moles of a reactant to $244 \,\mathrm{kJ}$. But isn't that $\Delta H$ the sum of all of the products or maybe all of them combined since it says that it is the $\Delta H$ of the REACTION?

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is not fully correct. $\Delta H$ for the reaction is the difference between the sum of $\Delta H_f$ for products minus the sum of $\Delta H_f$ for reactants. This works out because enthalpy is a measure of a potential (it is a state function), so the exact method of conversion (i.e. the path) between reactants and products doesn't matter, only the fact that we have a specific reactant and a specific product.